# Technical Documentation page navbar test

Tags: css, navbar

I'm doing the technical documentation page on freecodecamp and I'm not passing the test for User Story# 14 which is:

> User Story #14: On regular sized devices (laptops, desktops), the
> element with `id="navbar"` should be shown on the left side of the
> screen and should always be visible to the user.

Here's my CodePen : https://codepen.io/Codeoflulu/pen/KKWNENZ?editors=1100

```
#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  float: left;
}
```

It's the last test that I need to pass to move on to the next challenge and I'm stuck .

Comment: I think you should try a bit more. There are almost no style applied so far on your codepen.The idea here is not giving you the whole answer :)
 Btw, "text-color:blue;" is not a valid css rule. Use color:blue :)
You are in a good way with "position: fixed" though!

Comment: nothings seems to work im at 15//16 of the test passing